# Copied Code from One Note Book to Another Not Working

Tags: conda, google-colaboratory

I visited the [dataprofessor](https://github.com/dataprofessor) on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm2ak31u1us) who told me how to install conda onto the colab notebook.

I followed his instructions and made a copy of his notebook (Copy of conda-on-google-colab.ipynb) in my colab drive and ran everything.

It worked.  (I used conda to install scrapy.  This worked).

I started a new note book for a different project (but needing conda) and copied (ctrl-C, ctrl-V) the contents of his first cell to my first cell.  When I ran this, it didn't work.

```
################################################################################
# INSTALL CONDA ON GOOGLE COLAB
################################################################################
! wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
! chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
! bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
```

it just returns the following error,

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:4:8: unexpected symbol
3: ################################################################################
4: ! wget https
```

Can anyone help?  (Most probably something simple and obvious but eluding me).

Comment: I just ran it and it worked fine for me. Is that the only thing in the code cell you're running it in, or is there more code? Can you try to factory reset the runtime and see if it works?

Comment: @rchurt just ran it again after a factory reset.  I got the same error.  There is a work around in that I can copy the notebook from the dataprofessor but it seems strange that I can't just copy and paste a cell then run its contents.

Comment: Yeah, I copied the code you posted, pasted it into a cell in Colab, and it worked fine. Is there any other code in the cell?

Comment: @rchurt no there isn't any other code in the cell.  It is the very first cell too, so I haven't pre-installed anything (we just did a reset, anyway).

Comment: Are there any non-default settings for the notebook itself? Are you using a different kernel than python?

Comment: @rchurt I'm using the colabs environment.  Whatever that comes as ... but bear in mind that when I copied the whole code to my drive from the dataprofs github site and ran it within my colabs environment it worked.  It was only when I decided to set up a new project and copy only that cell, that it fell down.

Comment: Can you share the notebook and post a link here so I can run it?

Comment: @rchurt try this https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z_RFFijabebXS00q0RaqpQyGCjwrB526?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to run Python code with an R kernel.

Go to `Runtime -> Change runtime type -> Python 3`